# Capturing media button from headset on Motorola Razr Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, motorola, headset

This is my first post so if I do anything or phrase anything wrong please let me know for the future, and I am sorry if this is longer or more verbose then normal I just wanted to give a good background. Again if this isn't normal formatting please let me know because I would like to utilize, and contribute on this site more in the future.

I have an app I am maintaining, it controls what actions the headset button will do and has gesture recognition for single click, double click, long click, etc. The app has been working fine on all our test devices (Samsung Galaxy S3, Motorola Droid 4, and a few others running different versions of the android OS), but we recently got word that with the motorola razr the app wouldn't work at all.

I initially assumed that they were talking about the new hd running 4.1 but it is apparently the regular motorola razr running android 4.0.4 (atleast thats what our test device is running). We got some response from the app when plugged into our device, we could preform long clicks and single clicks but the device would not recognize gestures such as double click and on.

After googling for awhile I found many people talking about this problem in forums but I couldn't find any developers talking about potential fixes.

This is the only device I know of running 4.0.4 so I am going to start with more look into that build to see if there are some notes on it, but if anyone out there has worked on these devices and might know why this occurs I would appreciate any knowledge you have on the matter.

Comment: The more verbose and descriptive the better, in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out some more on this issue/the answer for my question. It turns out the app is running fine on the razr but the response time for the headset button is very slow on the device so the gesture recognition was timing out. But for future references if anyone encounters similar issues, the razr response time for me is no faster than 3 clicks per 600 milliseconds. (the fastest I got it to register was 616)